# Liferay,Dynamic Data List, template

Tags: templates, liferay, freemarker, velocity, dynamic-data-list

How can i create a template with velocity or Freemarker for DDL in liferay ?
I have a DLL with some data, i would display it not as a table but as a menu beacouse data is defined as [link,text]. 
i tried this code:
 `<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
<#if records?has_content>
    <#list records as cur_record>
     ll
    </#list>
</#if>`
in ddl there are 4 records, so this code would return ll ll ll ll , but it returns :
Expression ddlDisplayTemplateHelper is undefined on line 1, column 20 in 20155#20195#21230.

why? 
can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess it was clear, but to be on the safe side: The error message says that there's no variable called `ddlDisplayTemplateHelper` (or its value is `null`), so for some reason Liferay doesn't expose that tool to the template.

Comment: Yes, but how can i fix it?

Comment: What is that `ddlDisplayTemplateHelper`, I am unable to find any class with that name in **Liferay 6.2**. By the way what version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: May liferay versione is 6.2 ... I use That class because i find It in a forum but it never worked

Answer (score 0):

Using velocity, you can try something like this :

```
#set($records = $ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id))
#foreach($record in $records)
$record
#end
```

Comment: it doesn't show any error message but it doesn't diplay any record

Comment: If you tried it using velocity, you have to add  ddlDisplayTemplateHelper to the velocity context.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: context.put("ddlDisplayTemplateHelper ", "<DdlDisplayTemplateHelper object>");

have a look at this tutorial for velocity :
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html

Comment: is there an easier way to display data from a ddl?